# How to get an Absolute URI of a file that exists in codenameone FileSystemStorage?

Tags: codenameone

How to get an Absolute URI of a file that exists in codenameone FileSystemStorage?

In my project, I need to send a file that exists in CodeNameOne FileSystemStorage as an email attachment. I am using Message - getAttachments().put(...) method that forces me to use an uri (as string) of this file as a parameter.

How can I get this URI. Or better, How can I send a file in FileSistemStorage as an email attachment?

Comment: FYI file system storage requires that all paths be full paths and considers relative paths illegal as they are platform dependent see https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-use-storage-file-system-sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy, use FileSystemStorage.getAppHomePath(), and append your filename to the string it returns.

More here : https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/index.html